# Abstract Data Types and their Implementation

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, lists, data-sets, abstract-data-types

I wanted to know if there is good resource to learn about the ADTs like set ADT, list, array, boolean etc and their implementation.

Comment: Book recommendation requests generally don't work well here; they call for opinion, and our site format is not designed for opinion-based questions.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/874/755, https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1312/755, https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1360/755.  Can you identify specific requirements?  "Good" is a matter of opinion.  Can you tell us what books you've looked at so far and why they haven't met your needs?  If you can do that, your question might be a better fit.  If not, the question risks being closed by the community.

Answer (score 1):

I would say Algorithms by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne is a classic book which explains quite well the basics of these concepts.

However you could also find a lot of resources on the web for free.